# Print random value from selected key in python

Tags: python-2.6

I want to print a random value from a selected key. Inside the code are comments that explain the code.

```
cases = {
'wildfire' : {
    'blue' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'purple' : ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    'pink' : ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15'],
    'red' : ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20'],
    'knives' : ['k', 'b', 'f']
    },
'phoenix' : {
    'blue' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'purple' : ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    'pink' : ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15'],
    'red' : ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20'],
    'knives' : ['k', 'b', 'f']
    },
'gamma' : {
    'blue' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'purple' : ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    'pink' : ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15'],
    'red' : ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20'],
    'knives' : ['k', 'b', 'f']
    },
'chroma' : {
    'blue' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'purple' : ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    'pink' : ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15'],
    'red' : ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20'],
    'knives' : ['k', 'b', 'f']
    },
}
#First keys in dictionary are cases which can be selected by user
#The keys in cases dictionary are scaled from common to uncommon (top to               bottom)
#Values in the cases dictionary are the skins.
case_keys = 10
#case_keys are used to open cases
while case_keys >0:
resp=raw_input("Which case would you like to open? ")
for i in cases:
    if resp == i:
        chance = random.randint(1, 100)
        """HELP HERE. The skins are classed by rarity. E.g blue is common
but purple is more rare than blue and so forth. E.g blue is assigned to 25,
purple to 17, pink to 10, red to 5, knives to 1. E.g 45(chance) >= x,   output:blue is chosen, and from its list a random skin is selected."""
```

Output should be e.g: 8

I am using python 2.6. Unfortunately, I am unable to upgrade whatsoever.

Comment: Could you please elaborate some more on what you're trying to accomplish? What do you mean the output should be 8, when you have a formatted statement being printed? Are you trying to output "You've won a phoenix skin..." or "You've won a 8 skin..." or something else entirely?

Comment: User inputs a case name then another input is prompted. "Enter 'yes' to open". Which executes the rest of the script as shown. Output: "You've won a 8 skin" which is from random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be going out on a limb here, but maybe this will help

```
import random

cases = {
     'wildfire' : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
     'phoenix' : ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
     'gamma' : ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15'],
     'chroma' : ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20'],
    }


user_input = random.choice(cases.keys())
# user_input = one of 'wildfire', 'phoenix', 'gamma', or 'chroma'
index = random.randint(0, len(cases[user_input]))
# index = random integer between 0 and 4 used to index cases

chance = random.randint(1, 100)

for i, n in enumerate([35, 17, 5, 2]):
    if chance >= n:
        print "You've won a %s skin." % cases[user_input][index] + \
              " With a chance of, %s" % chance
        break
```

Sample outputs from running this snippet:

```
You've won a 15 skin. With a chance of, 84
You've won a 8 skin. With a chance of, 88
You've won a 20 skin. With a chance of, 76
```

Comment: Please see new edit. The answer is correct but I adjusted dictionary which requires more code.